# Chrome web extension giving error when executing script in active tab wtih "activeTab" permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using `activeTab` and `tabs` permissions in my `manifest.json` file, and I'm attempting to run the following code in my `background.js` file:

**background.js**

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: 'alert("test");'});
    });
});
```

This code should execute the script, `alert("test");`, on the *active* tab whenever *any* tab is updated.

However, it isn't working and I'm getting the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "https://example.com/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I did some research on the Google Web Extension documentation and discovered a few things. The "activeTab" permission allows the execution of scripts on the active tab. According to the documentation, my code should work, but it isn't.

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I understand that. I want my extension to work on all websites, so I would need broad host permissions. I don't want to use that permission unless I have to. I only need to execute a script on the active tab.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. I added the `activeTab` and `tabs` permissions. I want to write my code so that it does not need to use the `<all_urls>` permission.

Comment: According to the documentation, `<all_urls>` and `*://*` are both considered "broad host permissions," which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: I want to avoid broad host permissions so that my extension does not need to undergo a lengthy and somewhat annoying review process when I update the package in the Google Chrome Web Store. I'm not being problematic for no reason. According to the documentation, using the `activeTab` permission, it *is*, in fact, possible to execute scripts on the active tab without broad host permissions *regardless* of the web address.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I came at your question from the wrong end - removing comments now

Comment: The issue is probably when you are running the code as opposed to how you are - read [this documentation] to understand WHEN the extra privileges are granted - your code does not fall into those categories

Comment: As noted above, this model won't work. And I'd like to point out you don't need to use chrome.tabs.query - as you can see in the documentation onUpdated listener already receives parameters (tabId, changeInfo, tab) so you can use them directly. Also note the listener receives updates from all tabs, including inactive ones.

Comment: The code should execute the script on the *active tab* whenever *any tab* is updated.

Comment: As noted above, activeTab doesn't work like that, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).